Returning fixed size array
If I have a fixed-size 2D array T array[M][N],
I can access elements via array[i][j], and assert(sizeof(array[i]) == N * sizeof(T)).
How can I do it for array wrapped in a struct?
The following code allows to access elements via array[i][j] but fails the assert.
Is there a way for operator[] to return T[N] instead of T* ?
template<class T, int M, int N>
struct Array
{
    T data[M][N];

//  constexpr T[N] operator[] (int i) - CANNOT RETURN T[N]!
    constexpr T* operator[] (int i)
    {
        return data[i];
    }
}


Tried returning reference-to-array?  Something like T (&operator[](int i))[N]  It doesn't return by value, but the T* doesn't copy the contents of the slice, either.

You could return a std::span to the inner array.

This is why C++ as std::array

Note to future readers: Remember that sizeof on a pointer always provides the size of the pointer, not whatever is pointed at. A pointer only knows where something could be. It does not know if there really is a valid object or if that object is an array.

Returning a reference-to-array gives the sizeof you were looking for:
template<class T, int M, int N>
struct Array
{
    T data[M][N];

//  constexpr T[N] operator[] (int i) - CANNOT RETURN T[N]!
    constexpr T (&operator[](int i))[N]
    {
        return data[i];
    }
};

int main()
{
    Array<double, 2, 3> a;
    std::cout << sizeof(a) << ", " << sizeof(a[1]);
}

Introducing a type alias makes it easier to read
using row = T[N]; // or typedef T (&row)[N]

constexpr row& operator[](int i)
{
    return data[i];
}


And for const method it is:
`using row_const = T const[N];
constexpr const_row& operator[](int i) const
{
return data[i];
}` ?

@user2052436: Unnecessary, const row will work fine.  (And while the compiler will recognize both const row and row const, it does not treat const_row and row_const interchangeably)

The different ways to return reference to array
C++98/C++03 compatible ways:

Ugly way:
T (&operator[](int i))[N] { return data[i]; }


With typedef:
typedef T arr[N];

arr& operator[](int i) { return data[i]; }

or:
typedef T (&arr_ref)[N];

arr_ref operator[](int i) { return data[i]; }



Since C++11, in addition we have:

with decltype:
decltype(data[i]) operator[](int i) { return data[i]; }


trailing return type:
auto operator[](int i) -> T(&)[N] { return &f; }

or:
auto operator[](int i) -> decltype(data[i]) { return data[i]; }


typedef with using:
using arr = T[N];

arr& operator[](int i) { return data[i]; }

or:
using arr_ref = T(&)[N];

arr_ref operator[](int i) { return data[i]; }



Possibly with template using:
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
using CArray = T[N];

CArray<T, N>& operator[](int i) { return data[i]; }

C++14 adds:

auto deduction:
auto& operator[](int i) { return data[i]; }


decltype(auto) (but careful with deduced return type):
decltype(auto) operator[](int i) { return (data[i]); }



Alternatively, instead of C-array, using std::array would allow more natural syntax

Or you can make a wrapper like this :
(in general in C++ it should not be necessary to use sizeof all that much, specialy not to verify array sizes)
#include <array>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, std::size_t ROWS, std::size_t COLS>
class array2d_t final
{
public:
    array2d_t() = default;
    ~array2d_t() = default;

    array2d_t(const array2d_t&) = default;
    array2d_t& operator=(const array2d_t&) = default;
    array2d_t(array2d_t&&) = default;
    array2d_t& operator=(array2d_t&&) = default;

    explicit array2d_t(const int (&values)[ROWS][COLS]) 
    {
        std::size_t offset{0};
        for(std::size_t row{0ul}; row < ROWS; ++row)
        {
            for(std::size_t col{0ul}; col < COLS; ++col, ++offset)
            {
                m_values[offset] = values[row][col];
            }
        }
    }

    auto& at(std::size_t row, std::size_t col)
    {
        if ((row >= ROWS) || (col >= COLS)) throw std::invalid_argument{ "index out of range" };
        std::size_t offset = (COLS*row) + col;
        return m_values[offset];
    }

    const auto& operator()(std::size_t row, std::size_t col) const noexcept
    {
        std::size_t offset = (COLS*row) + col;
        return m_values[offset];
    }

    const auto& at(std::size_t row, std::size_t col) const
    {
        if ((row >= ROWS) || (col >= COLS)) throw std::invalid_argument{ "index out of range" };
        return operator()(row,col);
    }

    constexpr std::size_t rows() const noexcept { return ROWS;};
    constexpr std::size_t columns() const noexcept { return COLS;};

private:
    std::array<T,ROWS*COLS> m_values;
};


int main()
{
    array2d_t<int,2,2> matrix{{{0,1},{2,3}}};
}

